# Configuration of virtual directory for off-domain server in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, network-attached-storage, iis-8.5, virtual-directory

Setup:

- A web server (Windows 2012 R2, IIS 8.5) outside of domain (called MY_WEB_SERVER)
- A virtual directory pointing to a NAS server on a domain (called MY_NAS_SERVER)
- An application set on virtual directory to give the virtual directory its own app in the app pool (called AccessNAS)

Problem: The credentials are rejected by the NAS server, most likely because the ones IIS sends are not the ones we want it to send.

I have configured the app in app pool with a custom identity (username: MY_NAS_SERVER\nas_account). This account exists on the NAS. However, the connection is refused. If I look at ProcMon, I see two ACCESS_DENIED notices on CreateFile, and they both were attempted not using my given custom identity, but "MY_WEB_SERVER\nas_account".

How do I prevent the substitution of "MY_NAS_SERVER" with "MY_WEB_SERVER", so that the credentials I provide are the ones used?

And can this be done without a web.config file on the NAS server?

Comment: Have you tried creating a local account on the web server and the NAS server both with the same username and password? Then set the app pool to use that username and password.

Comment: @MassNerder Yes, that was my first attempt, but what I see in ProcMon is the Web server sending "MY_WEB_SERVER\nas_account" rather than "nas_account" or "MY_NAS_SERVER\nas_account". The NAS server refuses the "MY_WEB_SERVER\nas_account" name.

Comment: What about doing something like logging on as the app pool user, mapping a drive to to the NAS, then point your config to the drive.

Comment: @MassNerder That was suggested (and I really wanted that TBH) but rejected for other reasons. Namely that they want IIS to control everything.

Comment: have you tried using ".\username" in the app pool identity?

Answer (score 0):

IIS app pool has never worked as its advertised for me either.  You can't configure an app pool to a specific user and then access a file share with pass-through authentication.  You need to add specific user path credentials for each virtual directory.

Comment: Even so, this too fails.

Comment: Try changing to specific user path credentials and then redo the ProcMon.  You should also try connecting as WORKGROUP\nas_account instead of MY_NAS_SERVER\nas_account.

Comment: A workaround has been found, namely that the web servers were put on the domain. I couldn't test your solution. I really wanted to (with the workgroup). I'm giving you the prize nonetheless for your time.